# Cauchy's Integral Formula for calculating complex line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the integral
$$\int_a\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-3)}dz$$
with the paths

> 1. $a:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},x\mapsto2e^{it}$,
> 2. $a:[0,2\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C},x\mapsto2005+73e^{it}$.

My question is:

How can I use Cauchy's Integral Formula and Theorem to find these?
I know that the formula is $f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\, dz$, but how do I use it in these cases? Also isn't path $1$ the unit circle, which means that the integral is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Cauchy integral formula, $f(z)$ is a function that is analytic on the interior of $\gamma$. The function $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-3)}$ is analytic except at $z=1$ and $z=3$. The first path is not the unit circle, but rather the circle of radius 2 centered at the origin. The point $z=1$ is inside this circle, but $z=1$ is not. Thus, you can let $f(z)=1/(z-3)$, and $a=1$ and apply Cauchy's Integral Formula directly (and the answer will not be zero). The second path is a circle of radius $73$ centered at $2005$. It contains neither $z=1$ nor $z=3$, so $\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-3)}$ is analytic in the interior. What does Cauchy's theorem tell you about the integral?

Comment: For the second: that it is zero?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: And the result of the first is $-\pi i$?

Comment: I get $-4\pi i$.

Comment: Dont you get $-1/2=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int$?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. You're right.